# Rails 5: attr_accessor throwing NoMethodError (undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, attr

I have 2 non database attributes in my model. If one of them has a value, I need to return the other one in the json response:

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord

  attr_accessor :max_speed_on_track
  attr_accessor :track

  def attributes
    if !self.track.nil? 
      super.merge('max_speed_on_track' => self.max_speed_on_track)
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that the line 'if !self.track.nil?' throws an error when the controller tries to return the json

Perhaps there is a better way as I read that using attr_accessor is a code smell.

What I am trying to do is if the user passes me a track value as a query parameter, then I pass that value to the model and it uses it to calculate the `max_speed_on_track`, and return that value.

Obviously if no track is provided by the user then I don't want to return `max_speed_on_track` in the json.

The controller method is very basic for now (I still need to add the code that checks for the track param). The code throws the error on the save line.

```
  def create
    @car = Car.new(car_params)

    if @car.save
      render json: @car, status: :created
    else
      render json: @car.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

Comment: If this is only for when you call `to_json`, why not override the `as_json` method instead of the `attributes` method? Also, instead of doing `if !self.track.nil?`, you can use `if track.present?`. It reads easier.

Comment: Thanks but if self.track.present? throws the same error

Comment: I read this http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/ about as_json, but I am still stuck. What do I put inside the as_json method to include the field I want when track is not null, but exclude it when track has a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord

  attr_accessor :max_speed_on_track
  attr_accessor :track

  def as_json(options = {})
    if track.present?
      options.merge!(include: [:max_speed_on_track])
    end
    super(options)
  end
end
```

Since Rails uses the `attributes` method, and you're only needing this for json output, you can override the `as_json` method just like in [this article](http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/). This will allow you to include your `max_speed_on_track` method in your json output when the `track` is present (not nil).

Comment: Thank you, that works...but now I am starting to see the limitations here and I guess should move to RABL templates or ActiveModelSerialiazers.